# Using newline delimited list as parameter

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

There have been several situations where I have had some output such as

```
thing1
thing2
thing3
```

But have wanted to do something like:

```
*command* thing1
*command* thing2
*command* thing3
```

An example of this would be: let's say I want to kill all screen sessions.  Is there any way I can get one command to use somthing like:

```
screen -ls
```

which might result in

```
88.mine (detached)
22.mine (detached)
```

Can I do something that would result in all of the possible commands such as this:

```
screen -S 88.mine test -X
screen -S 88.mine test -X
```

in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 8):

Sure, just use `read`:

```
while read -r line; do
    command "$line"
done < file
```

In your more specific `screen` example, you need to remove the remaining text:

```
while read -r session _; do
    screen -S "$session" test -X
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of reading a newline separated list as input. The one you choose will depend on what exactly you are trying to do, but here are some simple examples:

- `while/read`

  ```
  $ printf "Tom\nDick\nHarry\n" | while read name; do echo "Hi $name"; done
  Hi Tom
  Hi Dick
  Hi Harry
  ```
- `for`

  ```
  $ for name in $(printf "Tom\nDick\nHarry\n"); do echo "Hi $name"; done
  Hi Tom
  Hi Dick
  Hi Harry
  ```